# Understanding "aggressively retiring" and "planes will be parked"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [13]​Delta airlines have a poorer record. Delta said it has been
>   aggressively retiring inefficient planes, such as 8 DC9s (average age:
>   38 years) that will be parked this year. In addition, the airline says
>   its mpg is impacted by having one of the industry’s highest passenger
>   and cargo load factors, which results in heavier aircraft, and having
>   a high percentage of short fights. In addition, Delta has a
>   significant presence on the East Coast, where delays are more
>   frequent.

What does "Delta said it has been aggressively retiring inefficient planes ... that will be parked this year" mean (in particular, the words "aggressively" and "park")?

Answer (score 1):

If you do something aggressively, it means that you do it with force and determination in order to succeed.

Usually, you retire from your job or your employer retires you, but you can also retire something  Here it means that you put it out of use or service.

You can park an aircraft just as you park your car.  I was an airliner. The word is in daily use.  But I think the verb ground is more appropriate in this context.  You ground an aircraft means that you park it in order to stop it from flying.

An aircraft is said to be inefficient when it's not performing in a satisfactory way or not producing desired results.

I think the meaning of the sentence the OP has asked about will come across with this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, "aggressively retiring" means Delta are retiring  the planes earlier than they normally would. "Park" means exactly that - the planes that are parked aren't to be flown again.